# Kotlin OkHttp api call promise

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working with developing the data source for my android app using Kotlin and having some issues that I am not sure what is going on or I am overthinking this. So android does not want you to execute networking on the main thread so you have to use the enqueue method in okHttp. What I am trying to do is to implement a promise like method that does a api call and then it it has a callback in a sense that is only ran once the execution of the api call is done.

I want to call this method and not do anything until a token is sent back from the server so that I can save it and also show the main activity for logged in users. I am pretty lose on how to do what I am trying to do? Do I have the right thinking on how to log in a user?

```
 fun login(username: String, password: String): Result<LoggedInUser> {
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://test.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()


        try {
            val service: AuthenticationService = retrofit.create(AuthenticationService::class.java)
            val userResponse: retrofit2.Call<LoggedInUser> = service.login(LoginRequest(username,password))
            val response = userResponse.enqueue(object : Callback<LoggedInUser> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoggedInUser>, t: Throwable) {
                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoggedInUser>,
                    response: Response<LoggedInUser>
                ) {
                    val user = response.body()
                    if (user != null){
                        return Result.Success(user)
                    }
                }

            })
//            val fakeUser = LoggedInUser(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane Doe","")
//            return Result.Success(fakeUser)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            return Result.Error(IOException("Error logging in", e))
        }
    }
```

Above is what I am trying to do return the logged in user after the call is done but I am getting a requires unit but found  Result.

Comment: What you have here should work fine but save yourself some headache and use [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: does retrofit have "promised" based calls like I am trying to do?

Comment: Check out the tutorials https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit

Answer (score 1):

I think you would try to use the `LoginResponse` `res` to generate the `LoggedInUser` or anything else. You can use a Kotlin callback (here `then: ((LoginResponse) -> Unit`) in this case-

```
fun authenticate(username: String, password: String, then: ((LoginResponse) -> Unit) {
    val url = "http:www.test.com"

    val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
        .add("email", username)
        .add("password", password)
        .build()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

    val client = OkHttpClient()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body?.string();

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val res = gson.fromJson(body, LoginResponse::class.java)
            APIToken.getInstance().put(APIToken.Key.API_TOKEN, res.token)
            then(res)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("error")
            println(call)
        }
    })
}
```

And then you can call this function like-

```
authenticate(userName, password){ LoginResponse res ->
    // use the response to do what you need to do
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am new to android dev but have done what I want in swift before. This way would allow me not to proceed until the http call is complete?

Comment: @user12039164 During the http call, it will wait but not block.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it also looks like it will be easier to use Retrofit for this case. But if you want to write it by yourself you can use `suspendCoroutine` which is extremely useful when you are trying to convert callbacks to coroutines.

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

class API {
    suspend fun authenticate(username: String, password: String): Deferred<LoggedInUser> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        async {
            suspendCoroutine<LoggedInUser> { continuation ->
                val url = "http:www.test.com"

                val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("email", username)
                    .add("password", password)
                    .build()

                val request = Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

                val client = OkHttpClient()

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                        val body = response.body()?.string()

                        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                        val res = gson.fromJson(body, LoginResponse::class.java)
                        APIToken.getInstance().put(APIToken.Key.API_TOKEN, res.token)
                        continuation.resume(LoggedInUser(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane DD","dfasdfasdf")) // return LoggedInUser
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                        println("error")
                        println(call)
                        continuation.resumeWithException(e) // fails with exception
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still trying to understand coroutines coming from the swift world. Netwr=ork call were not super hard in swift

Comment: yep, with Retrofit it will be easier :) OkHttp it's a pretty low level and usually, Android apps don't use it by itself

Comment: do I need t import anything for them I am getting errors on with context and some others like async

Comment: which version of coroutines you are using?